# Ubercart : How to display product information ( of certain brand ) as XML?

Tags: ubercart

Can the Ubercart module display product information of certain brand as XML ?

I have looked into Ubercart module settings, but I can't find anything useful.

Comment: Please use Catalog module to display product information of certain brand together and use rss feed to make it as xml

Comment: Okay, but how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the steps to create XML for certain product:

- Enable the catalog module
- add Brand as a term
- Create products and assign it to certain brand
- uc_catalog view is available for to show the listed product in certain brands
- make that view as RSS feed using [View RSS](http://drupal.org/project/views_rss) module